# Photos don't feel as "green" as they look to the eye

Tags: optics, visible-light

During a cycling trip yesterday, I took photos of plants I saw along the way with my phone (which is a Samsung Galaxy A21s), and observed that the green colour was significantly more "brownish" in the photo than it was to my eyes, while other colours like white, blue, purple were not that different. Is there some physical cause to this phenomenon, or that it's rather a problem of crappy phone camera?

P.S. I am not sure if this question suits PSE, or if it's actually more of a biology/phone-camera technical question.

Comment: Maybe ask on https://photo.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: This is more photography than physics, but the issue is kind of physical and psychological: camera sensors have different sensitivity from eyes, mapping the signal to a color value is nontrivial, and screens also do not have the same dynamical range as reality.

Comment: @Anders That's almost an answer...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for Photography SE.

Answer (score 3):

It is a camera thing, not physics. The software adjusts white balance to compensate for the color of the ambient light, aiming for natural colors.
Cameras assume the scene is mid-grey, essentially expecting a mixture of all colors.
Foliage is dominated by green, which throws off the algorithm.
Expensive cameras (and phones) have proprietary algorithms that “guess” the kind of scene and adjust the white balance accordingly; results may vary.

So yeah, it’s your phone that screws up.

Answer (score 2):

Phone cameras have color correction software in them which tint the camera response to yield a "pleasing" result. Some manufacturers dial down the green to yield more pleasing flesh tones for photographing faces, for example. And I'll bet that the newest generation of phone cameras recognize when faces are in the frame and adjust the color response automatically.

DSLR cameras have this capability too, but they also furnish a setting which defeats the autocorrect so the photographer can get a "raw" image file that can then be adjusted later exactly the way the photographer wants, before rendering a print.